# How to restrict UIButton height using NSLayoutConstraint

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, nslayoutconstraint

I have `UItoolbar` in which added two items 1. `UITextView` and 2. `UIButton`.
The Property of `UITextview` is to autogrowing based on entered text.
While growing of height of `UITextview` i want to restrict `UIButton` height, i.e `UIButton` height should not be increase.

```
[_toolbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:barButtonItemCommentText,barButtonItemSubmit,nil]];
submitBtn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
_toolbar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

[_toolbar addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-8-[textView]-79-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(textView)]];

 [_toolbar addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-8-[textView]-8-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(textView)]];

[_toolbar addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[submitBtn]-8-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(submitBtn)]];


[_toolbar addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-8-[submitBtn]-8-|" options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllBaseline metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(submitBtn)]];

[_toolbar addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:submitBtn
                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                    toItem:nil
                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute 
                                                multiplier:1.0 
                                                  constant:60]];
[textView setContentCompressionResistancePriority:UILayoutPriorityRequired forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal];
[textView setContentCompressionResistancePriority:UILayoutPriorityRequired forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisVertical];

[_toolbar setContentCompressionResistancePriority:UILayoutPriorityRequired forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisVertical];


[_toolbar addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_toolbar attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationLessThanOrEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1.0f constant:MaxToolbarHeight]];
```

For reference , see the attached screen-shot:

[image: Toolbar with autoresizeing UITextView and UIButton]

Comment: Maybe change this line `[_toolbar addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-8-[submitBtn]-8-|" options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllBaseline metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(submitBtn)]];` to this `[_toolbar addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|->=8-[submitBtn]-8-|" options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllBaseline metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(submitBtn)]];`

Comment: Thanks a lot @Dima, You have made my day.:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below mentioned constraint is making it to stretch in vertical direction as it ask to be always 8 pixels from top and bottom.

```
[_toolbar addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-8-[submitBtn]-8-|" options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllBaseline metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(submitBtn)]];
```

If you change it to constant height than it will not grow vertically, in this case always a height of 24.

```
[_toolbar addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[submitBtn(24)]-8-|" options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllBaseline metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(submitBtn)]];
```

Comment: I found that both the answers which are in comment of my question and your answers is works perfectly. Thanks Gandalf & Dima.